Is the following subset of positive semidefinite matrices a complete metric space?
Let $M>0$ be given. I came across the set $S=\{X\in M_n(\mathbb C): X\ \mbox{is positive semidefinite and}\ \mbox{tr}(X)\leq M\}$. Is $S$ a complete metric space? (Context: I want to apply Banach fixed point theorem).

What do you mean by a complex positive semidefonite matrix and what metric do you use?

If $M_N(\mathbb{C})$ is a complete metric space, your question becomes: is $S$ closed? Now, $S = \mathrm{tr}^{-1}((-\infty,M])$.

@AndréCaldas A bit more is needed, as $S$ is also restricted to positive semidefinite matrices. But one should be able to write that restriction also as an intersection of closed subsets.

@arkeet: oops... very true! :-)

Yes. $X$ being positive semidefinite means that $X^{\dagger} = X$ (I assume) and that $\langle v, Xv \rangle \ge 0$ for all $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$. Both of these are closed conditions (because the adjoint and the inner product are continuous; formally they express the positive semidefinite matrices as an intersection of closed subsets) so the subspace of positive semidefinite matrices is closed, and $\text{tr}(X) \le M$ is similarly also a closed condition (because the trace is continuous).
So $S$ is closed, hence complete (since $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is complete).

$\langle v, Xv \rangle \geq 0$ for all $v$ is enough to imply $X$ is positive semidefinite (in particular it already implies $X$ is self-adjoint - in fact $X$ being self-adjoint is equivalent to $\langle v, Xv \rangle \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $v$), so the first condition is unnecessary.

@David: Oh, I see, the situation is different over $\mathbb{C}$, I was thinking about the situation over $\mathbb{R}$. Just to fill in this small detail: $\langle v, Xv \rangle = \langle X^{\dagger} v, v \rangle = \overline{ \langle v, X^{\dagger} v \rangle }$, so if $\langle v, Xv \rangle$ is always real then $\langle v, Xv \rangle = \langle v, X^{\dagger} v \rangle$ which gives that $\langle v, (X - X^{\dagger}) v \rangle = 0$, and letting $v$ range over all eigenvectors of $X - X^{\dagger}$ gives that all its eigenvalues are zero, hence it is zero (by the spectral theorem).

(Just a note for anyone else who might be confused by this, over $\mathbb{R}$ if a matrix satisfies $\langle v, X v \rangle = 0$ then we can't conclude that it is zero, only that it is skew-symmetric, and the eigenvalues of a skew-symmetric matrix are purely imaginary so there are no real eigenvectors. So the last step fails, which means over $\mathbb{R}$ it is necessary to explicitly add the condition that positive semidefinite matrices are symmetric.)

Ah, that’s true. Over $\mathbb{R}$ that is indeed necessary. Over $\mathbb{C}$, the usage of spectral theorem is not necessary (in particular this doesn’t just work in finite dimensions). An alternative approach is to note that the complex version of the polarization identity applies to any sesquilinear form (instead of just symmetric ones, as in the real case), so any two sesquilinear forms that coincide on the diagonal are necessarily the same everywhere. In particular, $\langle v, A^\ast v \rangle = \langle v, Av \rangle$ for all $v$ implies $A = A^\ast$.
